# Update Gnome on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gnome, updates

I installed gnome on Ubuntu 16.04. I used the package **ubuntu-gnome-desktop**

My question : Is there any safe way to update gnome to 3.22? Also did i installed gnome correctly? Right now i am using Gnome-Shell 3.18.5

Comment: The answer primarily depends on what you mean by "safe way"?

Comment: i mean a way that wont 't break my ubuntu installation.

Comment: I have quite a bit of experience with trying to install GNOME on other flavours, and let's just say that whenever I tried to just install GNOME rather than do a fresh install of Ubuntu GNOME, it all ended in disaster. So no, I would not say that you did it the "safe way". The safest way to do it would be to put Ubuntu GNOME on a LiveUSB and do a fresh install of it or get it running in a VM.

Comment: I installed  gnome from the ubuntu repository. Everything went fine. I even updated gnome from 3.18 to 3.20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no official way to update gnome to the latest release without using ppa's.  However, they generally work very well.  This website should give you the instructions you need:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/05/install-gnome-3-20-ubuntu-16-04-lts

> We’ll use the Terminal to add the two GNOME 3 PPAs:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
> ```
>
> Next, refresh your software sources:
>
> ```
> sudo apt update
> ```
>
> Finally upgrade (if you already have GNOME-Shell
>   installed) using:
>
> ```
> sudo apt dist-upgrade
> ```
>
> Or install GNOME (if you don’t already use it):
>
> ```
> sudo apt install gnome gnome-shell
> ```

Comment: Thank you i will try it. Did i installed gnome correctly using the **ubuntu-gnome-desktop** package?

Comment: Yep, and the ppa's will add the newer packages.  You can choose how "bleeding-edge" you're willing to go.  I generally find most of them very stable.

Comment: If something goes wrong can i reverse? and how?

Comment: @UnstoppableGR Install *ppa-purge*. Then use it against the Gnome PPA you added before: *sudo ppa-purge ppa:(...)* . It removes the PPA and reverses any changes made. The end result is the downgrade to the stardard packages before adding the PPA.

Comment: Actually i just updated to gnome 3.20 and everything went fine. But when i first logged in i was getting a message **System program problem detected**  i ran **sudo rm /var/crash/*** in the terminal, i restarted and i dont get the message anymore.  I didnt get any log why i got this message just a report problem button.

Comment: You will get some errors messages like that, but they're mostly safe to ignore.