# How to upgrade GTK 3.18 to 3.20 on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, gnome, gtk3

While trying to install lollypop I got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lollypop/container.py", line 79, in update_db
    self.__show_first_run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lollypop/container.py", line 335, in __show_first_run
    view = FirstRunView()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lollypop/view_first_run.py", line 29, in __init__
    builder.add_from_resource("/org/gnome/Lollypop/FirstRunView.ui")
GLib.Error: gtk-builder-error-quark: .:3:50 Required gtk+ version 3.20, current version is 3.18 (7)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you [Google this](https://www.google.com/search?q=install+gtk+3.20+ubuntu&oq=install+&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0l2j69i60j0.3840j0j7&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), you will find guides like [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/05/install-gnome-3-20-ubuntu-16-04-lts) and [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/04/how-to-install-gnome-320-in-ubuntu.html). In addition, you will find that this has been asked before on this very site at least twice: once in [2016](https://askubuntu.com/questions/830832/update-gnome-on-ubuntu-16-04?rq=1) and once in [2015](https://askubuntu.com/questions/625244/how-to-upgrade-to-the-latest-gnome-version?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Now, to be fair, I'm used to `arch`, which already ships with 3.20. Being maybe 1 year after the release of 3.20, I almost didn't believe the Ubuntu guides above. Really? Add a separate repository, including one with `staging` in the name? Nevertheless, it's true and the tl;dr is very simple:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

I did these exact steps today, rebooted for good measure, and enjoyed that my preferred `openbox` themes (which work fine on `arch`) were no longer messed up (due to `3.18`, which I never would have suspected).

Comment: Just as a point of information this is the first search result for [upgrade gtk to 3.20], so someone might land on this page after a reasonable effort to Google it. Thanks for the helpful links.

Comment: It's GNOME3. The question is about GTK3. Are they the same?

Comment: @DongNguyen I think it's just the name of the repository. Take a look at the [list of packages](https://launchpad.net/%7Egnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3-staging/+index?field.series_filter=xenial&batch=75&memo=75&start=75) in said repository and you'll see an awful lot of `3.20` values for the versions, including `gtk+3.0`. So yes, I think the answer is accurate: adding this staging repo will updates one's gtk-relevant packages to `3.20`.

Comment: I thing that is for installing the whole Gnome3 DE.

Comment: You're welcome to try it and/or post your own answer. Note that none of the commands above involve `install pkgname`; so nothing is installed. It simply adds a repo which triggers `apt update` to see a newer version of relevant packages that are *already* installed, and it updates them.

Comment: 'google it'? Really? Well I did and it brought me here. I think it's really poor form to answer questions with something that starts with 'google it'. The rest of the answer is good though :-)

Comment: @kris Yeah, really. I only answered this because I'd done it myself based on other guides (that come up with google; just click my link). I think it's bad form to ask answered questions, and StackExchange seems to agree by closing duplicates. In fact, this 2017 question duplicates one from [2016](https://askubuntu.com/questions/830832/update-gnome-on-ubuntu-16-04) which duplicates one from [2015](https://askubuntu.com/questions/625244/how-to-upgrade-to-the-latest-gnome-version?noredirect=1&lq=1). All have the same info.

Comment: @Hendy sure. I understand. And pointing to places where you found information is very good. Also pointing out that the question has been asked and answered before, those are all good and helpful things to do. I just think you can do all that without saying 'google it'. That just sounds very condescending. And there's really no need for that.

Comment: @kris Fair point. I toned it down just now, linked directly to the previous versions, and marked this question as a duplicate. Seem reasonable? Thanks for your input.

Comment: Facing segmentation fault on some apps after dist-upgrade, the ppa itself suggest to do ppa-purge for Ubuntu older than 18.04, see this: https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3-staging